# Trying to take handwritten digits and turning them into an integer with keras mnist and python (error)

Tags: python, keras

so i am currently trying to take handwritten digits and turning them into an integer in python, but i just get a lot of errors with numpy arrays and such. i followed a lot of tutorials and tried to code something from them but it just doesn't want to work.

i have this code for training my model:

```
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow import keras
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
def main():
    mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    num_train = X_train.shape[0]
    num_test = X_test.shape[0]

    img_height = X_train.shape[1]
    img_width = X_train.shape[2]
    X_train = X_train.reshape((num_train, img_width * img_height))
    X_test = X_test.reshape((num_test, img_width * img_height))

    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)

    num_classes = 10
    xi = Input(shape=(img_height*img_width,))
    xo = Dense(num_classes)(xi)
    yo = Activation('softmax')(xo)
    model = Model(inputs=[xi], outputs=[yo])

    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=20,
          verbose=1,
          validation_split=0.1)

    score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print('Test loss:', score[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
    model.save("mnist_model.h5")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And i think this code just works because it gives me a valid file,
but when i try to predict a digit with this model with the code below, it gives me a ton of errors whatever i try...

main code (there is more to for example get the individual digits out of a whole number, but i don't think that is te problem):

```
from keras.saving.save import load_model
from tensorflow import keras
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

model = load_model("mnist_model.h5")
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


def predict_digit(img):
    # # resize image to 28x28 pixels
    img = img.resize((28, 28))
    # convert rgb to grayscale
    img = img.convert('L')
    img = np.array(img)
    # reshaping to support our model input and normalizing
    img = img / 255.0
    img = img.reshape((1,784))
    # predicting the class

    res = model.predict(img)
    # print(res)
    return np.argmax(res), max(res)

digit, acc = predict_digit(digit_image)
print(str(digit) + ', ' + str(int(acc * 100)) + '%')
```

and when i run the code it gives me an error on the line:

> print(str(digit) + ', ' + str(int(acc * 100)) + '%')

the error is:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

But there are probably some more things wrong with my code :/ so i hope someone can help me !

Answer (score 1):

The model expects an input of `28x28=784` pixels, but reshaping the image with `img = img.reshape(1, 28)` reduces the dimension, making it incompatible. Try commenting out this layer and see what happens!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i commented out the img.reshape, and it gives me about the same error:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 784), found shape=(None, 28)

Comment: Please update your question with your current (problem) code. The only way you're getting expected shape 784 is if you're still using the code in the current question.

Comment: your code indicates that you want a flat input of 784 neurons, so your prediction input should be shaped as such. You are using the resize layer, adding an extra dimension to your data. The model interprets this as having 28 samples, each with 28 variables. Try keras.layers.reshape((1, 784)) so the shape matches your initial X input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but where exactly would i add this line?

Comment: My apologies for lack of specificity! Try replacing `img = img.resize((28, 28))` with `img = img.reshape((784))`. Hopefully that makes the shape of your model input and the image you want to predict match up

Comment: Thanks again, now i get an error on a totaly other line:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryanv\Desktop\python htr\main.py", line 83, in <module>
    print(str(digit) + ', ' + str(int(acc * 100)) + '%')
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

witch i think is an error about the result handeling (i changed the line img = img.resize((28, 28))  to  img = img.reshape((1, 784)) like you said)

Comment: It seems like the predict function works now, which is good at least. The error is saying that either `digit` or `acc` has a dimension larger than one, so it cannot be converted to a scalar; based on this message, I think `acc` has multiple dimensions and can't be converted to int. What is your `digit_image.shape`?

Comment: digit_image.shape is not a valid attribute: "AttributeError: shape"  But is you mean the size, then all the digits i process have a differrent size because of the way i take them out of a full number (for example my code turns an image of 2204 into an image of: 2, 2, 0 and 4) If you want to see this code tell me :)   Oh and thank you so much for all the help btw!